# kendogrid binding with an observable array

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-grid

I am trying with an example of binding a knockout observable array to kendogrid, but not successful.

Below is the code where I have created an observable array called- **AllUsers**, it is an array of User object.

```
define(['kendo'], function (kendo) {

    function user(userID) {
        return {
            userID: ko.observable(userID),
        };
    }

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        attached: attached,
        AddUser: AddUser,
        AllUsers: ko.observableArray([]),
        userID: ko.observable(),

    };

    return vm;

    function activate() {
        return true;
    }

    function attached() {

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: vm.AllUsers,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            height: 250,
            pageable: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            columns: [{
                field: 'userID',
                title: 'User ID',
                width: 200
            },
            {
                command: 'destroy',
                title: ' ',
                width: 150
            }]
        });

        return true;
    }

    function AddUser() {

        vm.AllUsers.push(new user("testing"));

        return true;
    }
});
```

The html code for the same:

```
<div id="header" class="form-horizontal form-widgets">
        <fieldset>

            <label for="userID" class="required" style="margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px">User Id</label>
            <input id="userid" style="margin-right:20px" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: userID" required />
            <button type="button" id="addUserButton" data-bind="click: AddUser" style="margin-bottom:30px">Add user</button>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with the binding?
On click of add user button, the user should be added to the observableArray and then should reflect in the grid. Both are not happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The kendoGrid needs to deal with plain objects. So, you could bind against something like:

```
dataSource: ko.toJS(vm.AllUsers)
```

This would recursively unwrap any observables and return a plain object.

When you add a new item to your observable array, you would have to let the KendoGrid know that your data source has changed. For example, you could subscribe to any array changes on the observableArray and make updates to the grid like:

```
vm.AllUsers.subscribe(function(changes) {
   var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
       dataSource = grid && grid.dataSource;

    if (dataSource) {
        //loop through changes make any adds
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(changes, function(change) {
            if (change && change.status === "added") {
               dataSource.add(ko.toJS(change.value));   
            }
        });
    }
}, vm, "arrayChange");
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/E8dMq/

You can also explore using the Knockout-Kendo bindings here: http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/, if you want more integration.

Comment: thanks for the reply and fiddle link. how to get the delete command work?

Comment: @user2439903 - here is a sample with delete working: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Wn75e/

Comment: thanks for the link. I followed the code in this link [link]http://jsfiddle.net/D3rSk/7/  . How does the delete button work? i cant get the same code working in my code base.

Comment: the grid has to have "editable: true" and then a "remove" handler is added that matches up the id and removes it from the observableArray.